# How do I "get item" with an integer?

Tags: python-2.7, integer

I was wondering how I could do the "get item function" on an integer.

For example:

```
x='abcde'
print x[0:3]
```

That would print out `abc`

I was wondering how I would do that with integers.

I tried this:

```
x=12345
print x[0:3]
```

That doesn't work. Is there a way to do this for integers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = 12345
print str(x)[0:3]
```

We convert the integer to a string, perform the string slicing and print it.

If you want to store it as a number:

```
new_x = int(str(x)[0:3])
```

You can omit the `0` in `[0:3]` and simply write this: `[:3]`.